# Four Hundred Blows

Tags: idiom-requests, french

The French expression *faire les quatre cents coups* seems to mean ‘to cause trouble in every possible way’.  François Truffaut used the phrase for his movie [*Les quatre cents coups*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053198) (1959), known in English by a literal translation *The 400 Blows*, though that's opaque.  (I think *strokes* would be a better translation than *blows*, but it wouldn't help the opacity.)

So I try to think of an English idiom that would capture the sense.  All I've got so far is *Every Trick in the Book*, which still is not quite satisfactory: it can mean delinquency but its primary connotation is cunning.  Can you do better?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the French phrase or whether it has idiomatic meaning. From your description, it's hard to infer context. Would a speaker using that phrase be referring to he or she himself "delivering 400 blows", as if he or she is the instigator, or would the phrase instead refer to someone being pummeled by so many blows, as if he or she is being assaulted from all directions?

Comment: "in every possible way" is the only part that aligns with "every trick in the book". The latter is not synonymous with causing trouble: "I tried every trick in the book to get my computer working"; in this case the tricks are used to *avert* the trouble. Can you provide a context?

Comment: Wikipedia s.v. Four Hundred Blows says the original subtitler suggested *Wild Oats*.

Comment: @RMac The French expression [does have idiomatic meaning](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/actualite/lorigine-de-ces-fameuses-expressions-faire-les-quatre-cents-coups). Originally it (probably) referred to having survived 400 cannon shots. By Truffaut's time the expression was established in a figurative sense, meaning to have a wild life (not necessarily delinquency per se, it emphasizes the care-free aspect rather than any harm). Nowadays, when people here the expression, they think Truffaut's movie.

Comment: @CharlieHanson:  “I live in terror of what Junior will get up to next; he's already pulled every trick in the book.”  —Maybe I only imagined that someone somewhere once said such a thing.

Comment: The only other place I remember seeing the French phrase is in the comic strip _Gaston Lagaffe_.  At the end of strip #600, a policeman asks, “Isn't that the lad who has already done the 400 coups?”  Gaston's boss replies, “No, SIX hundred!”

Comment: The phrase has also on occasion been used in other languages, translated verbatim. The Swedish band Kent, for instance, have a song called _400 slag_, where the chorus line goes, “Så du står giv akt med din rygg rak och tar fyra hundra slag” (‘So you stand attention with your back straight and take your four hundred blows’).

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the French expression has a wider meaning than the one you are suggestion. The following ***[source](http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/faireles400coups.htm)*** gives a few  hints:

> - to raise hell, live a wild life, sow one's wild oats

and notes that:

> - Many expressions can't be translated literally between French and English, but the French expression faire les quatre cents coups is one that makes virtually no sense at all - you can't even guess  as to what it means figuratively.I think it is partly the definite articles *les* ("the") that makes it so difficult, as if there are 400 specific tricks that one must do in order to claim that you've lived a truly wild life.

Also

> - ....the word coup has numerous meanings; in faire les quatre cents coups, it's in the sense of un mauvais coup - "a dirty or mean trick." Unfortunately, the title of the François Truffaut's film Les Quatre Cents Coups was poorly translated as "The 400 Blows" in English. "400 Tricks" would have been a little better, but I think the best translation would have been something more figurative like "Raising Hell" or "The Wild One."

Answer (score 1):

There's not one single English phrase that will match exactly *Faire les quatre cents coups*. It is used to describe unruly behaviour, with a greater or lesser degree of "unruliness". In the context of the film that deals with teenage rebellion and delinquency* I expect the best translation would be "Raising hell" which has [sometimes been used by film reviews](http://www.dca.org.uk/whats-on/event/the-400-blows-les-400-coups).

I agree with what is said on the blog [Mislaid In Translation](http://mislaidintranslation.blogspot.fr/2010/05/les-400-coups-400-blows.html) that "*sow one's wild oats*" would not do to translate the title of Truffaut's film because the English phrase implies more sexual (mis)behaviour than is present in the film. On the other hand I disagree when they imply that  the French expression does not carry any sexual meaning. *Faire les 400 coups* can include sexual (mis)behaviour in a different context from that of the film.
*Faire les quatre cents coups* is defined as:

> *faire beaucoup de bêtises, d'excès, mener une vie de débauche* (Dictionnaire Culturel en Langue Française)

which means "Get into mischief, lead a life of excess and debauchery", so indeed it can imply sexual (mis)behaviour.

When possible (so not in Truffaut's film) I like to translate *faire les quatre cents coups* with "Paint the town red". Both phrases have a historical background, [*Faire les quatre cents coups*](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/actualite/lorigine-de-ces-fameuses-expressions-faire-les-quatre-cents-coups), [Paint the town red](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/paint-the-town-red.html) and they both divert a concrete image into a figurative one.

For those who can read French, (*[Faire les quatre cents coups](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0Y0uBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT154&lpg=PT154&dq=balzac%20%22faire%20les%20quatre%20cents%20coups%22&source=bl&ots=mq1Bl2jZ_K&sig=MXLVo5UncQN0Ko19fE2pF1KEQfI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjroLDU0-3OAhUBmBoKHXuOD6MQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=balzac%20%22faire%20les%20quatre%20cents%20coups%22&f=false)*) in a contemporary phrase book.

*<sup>The film came out in 1959 and what was called "teenage delinquency" is far from what it means in the 21st century.</sup>